# Navigate table cells using up,down,left,right buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a program in JavaScript that's supposed to allow the user to navigate between table cells using up,down,left,right buttons.  The appropriate table cell is highlighted after a directional button is clicked.

My table looks like this:

[image]

I'm working on building the functions to control the directional buttons, but I'm extremely lost on how to approach this. I need to be able to pass an argument that contains the currently highlighted cell, but I can't figure out how to do that.

My JavaScript so far, which doesn't really do much:

```
function right() {
    document.getElementById("one").nextElementSibling.style.border = '2px solid black';
}
```

Any help on how to deal with this would be great, because I really have no idea how to go about it.

Comment: please create a jsfiddle with the HTML table

Comment: You may not want to do it - but using jQuery will certainly help you structure this in a simpler and more readable way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A DYNAMIC SOLUTION USING PURE JS**

You can essentially store the table objects in a 2-d matrix. While doing this have two global coordinates X and Y that store the current grid location. You can bind click events and keyboard events that track where the current focus is.

Take a look at the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cnkr7wqa/5/

Note that this solution is dynamic regardless of the row size or the column size **if every row is the same length and every column is the same length.**

Also note that this works for: **mouse clicks, directional keyboard presses, and button presses**

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>9</td>
</tr>
</table>

<button>Left</button>
<button>Up</button>
<button>Right</button>
<button>Down</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
var dat = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
var numOfColumns = document.getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
var numOfRows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
var currIndex = 0;
var rowObj = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var oneColLength = rowObj[0].children.length;
var colObj = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
var totalData = rowObj.length * colObj.length;
var dataCounter = 0;
var matrixObj = new Array(rowObj.length);
var currentX = 0;
var currentY = 0;
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for(var i = 0; i < matrixObj.length; i++){
   matrixObj[i] = new Array(oneColLength);
}

for(var i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++){
  for(var j = 0; j < oneColLength; j++){
     matrixObj[i][j] = colObj[dataCounter++];
  }
}

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    removeAllBorders();
    compareBtnEntity(this);
  });
}

for(var i = 0; i < dat.length; i++){
  dat[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    removeAllBorders();
    this.style.border = "1px solid red";
    compareEntity(this);
  });
}

window.addEventListener("keyup",function(e){
       switch(e.keyCode){
            case 37: 
                if(currentX > 0){
                  currentX--;
                  repaint();
                }
                break;
            case 38: 
                if(currentY > 0){
                  currentY--;
                  repaint();
                }
                break;
            case 39: 
                if(currentX < oneColLength-1){
                  currentX++;
                  repaint();
                }
                break;
            case 40: 
                if(currentY < matrixObj.length-1){
                  currentY++;
                  repaint();
                }
                break;          
        }
})

function removeAllBorders(){
  for(var i = 0; i < dat.length; i++){
    dat[i].style.border = "1px solid grey";
  }
}

function compareEntity(ele){
  for(var i = 0; i < matrixObj.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < oneColLength; j++){
       if(ele == matrixObj[i][j]){
          currentX = j;
          currentY = i;
       }
    }
  }
}

function compareBtnEntity(ele){
        for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
            if(buttons[i] == ele){
                break; 
            }
        }

    switch(i){
                case 0: 
                if(currentX > 0){
                  currentX--;
                  repaint();
                }
                break;
            case 1: 
                if(currentY > 0){
                  currentY--;
                  repaint();
                }
                break;
            case 2: 
                if(currentX < oneColLength-1){
                  currentX++;
                  repaint();
                }
                break;
            case 3: 
                if(currentY < matrixObj.length-1){
                  currentY++;
                  repaint();
                }
                break;       
      }
     repaint();
  }


function repaint(){
  removeAllBorders();
  matrixObj[currentY][currentX].style.border = "1px solid red";
}
```

Comment: I get some weirdness when clicking on cells then going to the buttons. For instance, click on cell 3 then click Right. It hilights cell 8. [Example](http://i.imgur.com/spbQszW.gif)

Comment: @romellem good catch! I had the `i` and `j` variables assigned to the opposite axis in the `compareEntity` function. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

I know you didn't include the `jquery` tag on this, but I made a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/romellem/pg6eveht/) (https://jsfiddle.net/romellem/pg6eveht/) using jQuery to make things a bit easier.

There isn't anything overly complex where you couldn't strip out the jQuery I used, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. :)

I used the prototype pattern to make a hilighter class where you pass a selector to initialize a table. It doesn't account for Headers in the table, so you'll need to add that.

Otherwise, hopefully this helps you take a step in the right direction if you're totally lost.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var TableHilighter = function(table, selected) {
    this.table = $(table);
    this.rows = this.table.find('tr').length;
    this.cols = this.table.find('tr').first().find('td').length;
    this.selected = (typeof selected === 'undefined') ? [1, 1] : selected;

    // Hilight our row on initialization
    this.hilight();
  };

  TableHilighter.prototype = {
    "hilight": function(cell) {
      if (typeof cell === 'undefined') {
        cell = this.selected;
      }
      // Clear all hilighted cells
      this.table.find('td').removeClass('hilighted');

      // First find the row, then find the col, and add the .hilighted class
      this.table.find('tr:nth-child(' + this.selected[1] + ')').find('td:nth-child(' + this.selected[0] + ')').addClass('hilighted');
    },
    "move": function(dir) {
      switch (dir) {
        case 'up':
          this._up();
          break;
        case 'down':
          this._down();
          break;
        case 'left':
          this._left();
          break;
        case 'right':
          this._right();
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      this.hilight();
      return this.selected;
    },
    "_left": function() {
      if (this._x() > 1) {
        this._x(this._x() - 1);
      }
      return this.selected;
    },
    "_right": function() {
      if (this._x() < this.cols) {
        this._x(this._x() + 1);
      }
      return this.selected;
    },
    "_up": function() {
      if (this._y() > 1) {
        this._y(this._y() - 1);
      }
      return this.selected;
    },
    "_down": function() {
      if (this._y() < this.rows) {
        this._y(this._y() + 1);
      }
      return this.selected;
    },
    "_x": function(x) {
      if (typeof x === 'undefined') {
        return this.selected[0];
      } else {
        this.selected[0] = x;
        return this.selected[0];
      }
    },
    "_y": function(y) {
      if (typeof y === 'undefined') {
        return this.selected[1];
      } else {
        this.selected[1] = y;
        return this.selected[1];
      }
    }
  };

  // Initialize our TableHilighter
  var my_table = new TableHilighter('table');

  // Add button event handlers
  $('.up').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    my_table.move('up');
  });

  $('.down').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    my_table.move('down');
  });

  $('.left').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    my_table.move('left');
  });

  $('.right').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    my_table.move('right');
  });
});
```

```css
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}
.hilighted {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 1px;
}
button.up {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
button.down {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1,1</td>
    <td>2,1</td>
    <td>3,1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1,2</td>
    <td>2,2</td>
    <td>3,2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1,3</td>
    <td>2,2</td>
    <td>3,3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button class="up">Up</button>

<div>
  <button class="left">Left</button>
  <button class="right">Right</button>
</div>

<button class="down">Down</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

A convenient way to deal with this problem is to give meaningful `id`'s to your cells. Navigation becomes self-explanatory then.

```js
var dimensionX = 4;
var dimensionY = 4;
var selected = "cell-0-0";

$(document).keydown(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  $("#" + selected).removeClass("selected");
  var currentX = parseInt(selected.split("-")[1]);
  var currentY = parseInt(selected.split("-")[2]);

  switch (event.which) {
    case 37:
      selected = "cell-" + (currentX == 0 ? dimensionX - 1 : currentX - 1) + "-" + currentY;
      break;

    case 38:
      selected = "cell-" + currentX + "-" + (currentY == 0 ? dimensionY - 1 : currentY - 1);
      break;

    case 39:
      selected = "cell-" + ((currentX + 1) % dimensionX) + "-" + currentY;
      break;

    case 40:
      selected = "cell-" + currentX + "-" + ((currentY + 1) % dimensionY);
      break;
  }
  $("#" + selected).addClass("selected");
});

$("#up, #down, #left, #right").click(function() {

  var currentX = parseInt(selected.split("-")[1]);
  var currentY = parseInt(selected.split("-")[2]);
  $("#" + selected).removeClass("selected");

  switch (this.id) {
    case "up":
      selected = "cell-" + currentX + "-" + (currentY == 0 ? dimensionY - 1 : currentY - 1);
      break;
    case "down":
      selected = "cell-" + currentX + "-" + ((currentY + 1) % dimensionY);
      break;
    case "left":
      selected = "cell-" + (currentX == 0 ? dimensionX - 1 : currentX - 1) + "-" + currentY;
      break;
    case "right":
      selected = "cell-" + ((currentX + 1) % dimensionX) + "-" + currentY;
      break;
  }
  $("#" + selected).addClass("selected");
});

$("#mark").click(function() {
  if ($("#" + selected).hasClass("marked")) $("#" + selected).removeClass("marked");
  else $("#" + selected).addClass("marked");
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td.selected {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
p.buttons > span {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px 3px;
}
td.marked {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="sheet">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="row-0">
      <td id="cell-0-0" class="selected">A</td>
      <td id="cell-1-0">B</td>
      <td id="cell-2-0">C</td>
      <td id="cell-3-0">D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row-1">
      <td id="cell-0-1">E</td>
      <td id="cell-1-1">F</td>
      <td id="cell-2-1">G</td>
      <td id="cell-3-1">H</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row-2">
      <td id="cell-0-2">I</td>
      <td id="cell-1-2">J</td>
      <td id="cell-2-2">K</td>
      <td id="cell-3-2">L</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row-3">
      <td id="cell-0-3">M</td>
      <td id="cell-1-3">N</td>
      <td id="cell-2-3">O</td>
      <td id="cell-3-3">P</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p class="buttons"><span id="up">Up</span> <span id="down">Down</span>  <span id="left">Left</span> <span id="right">Right</span> <span id="mark">Mark</span></p>
```

You need to focus the snippet in order to use arrows to move around.